# Image swap with a javascript onclick dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, drop-down-menu

So I've got this code that has an image and when you click it a dropdown menu appears. Pretty simple. The code works fine but I'm trying to incorporate an image swap on click and I'm having difficulty. Here's the HTML and the JS (there's some CSS too, but I'll leave that out):

HTML:

```
<div id="header">
  <dl class="dropdown">
    <dt><a href="#"><img src="images/cogwheel_btn.png"/></a></dt>
    <dd>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Favorites</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
    </ul>
    </dd>
  </dl>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".dropdown dt a").click(function() {
    $(".dropdown dd ul").toggle();
});     
$(".dropdown dd ul li a").click(function() {
    var text = $(this).html();
    $(".dropdown dt a span").html(text);
    $(".dropdown dd ul").hide();
    $("#result").html("Selected value is: " + getSelectedValue("sample"));
});       
function getSelectedValue(id) {
    return $("#" + id).find("dt a span.value").html();
}
$(document).bind('click', function(e) {
    var $clicked = $(e.target);
    if (! $clicked.parents().hasClass("dropdown"))
    $(".dropdown dd ul").hide();
});
});
```

I've tried adding lines like ("dt").empty(); and then ("dt").html("new_image") but it causes the dropdown functionality to stop working. Anyone any ideas?

Comment: should your img inside your dropdown have the class `.flag` on it in your html?

Comment: Eh, I've to tweak this code that someone else wrote, so I'm not sure to be honest... I think you're right though, some of the code has become obsolete through different changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll be wanting to update the src attribute of your image -

You can find the image in the dropdown like this:

```
$('.dropdown dt img')
```

Then update the src attribute

```
$('.dropdown dt img').attr('src', '/newimage.jpg');
```

I suspect you'll want this in the click function like so:

```
$(".dropdown dt a").click(function() {
    $(".dropdown dd ul").toggle();
    $('.dropdown dt img').attr('src', '/newimage.jpg');
});
```

Note that if you want it to toggle on/off, you could check for the visibility of the `ul` element with the [`.is(':visible')`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) check. Or better still, replace the image with a div, and use a background image changed with [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/).

Comment: How would that ul element visibility check look? like... if $("dropdown dd ul").is('visible') { $('.dropdown dt img').attr('src', 'images/image.png'); ??

Answer (score 1):

I have created code at JSFiddle. Just check if this is how you would like it to behave:

http://jsfiddle.net/3L3At/2/

Comment: You will need to wrap the code inside $(document).ready(function() {

Comment: Also please see that I have added the ID tag to ul and img. You will need to incorporate that.